# click and current_path with rspec-rails and capybara

Tags: capybara, rspec-rails

this code

```
describe "HomePages" do
    subject {page}
    before { visit root_path }

    describe "navigation" do
        describe "click signup" do
            before {find_button('Sign up').click}
            current_path.should == sign_up_path
        end

    end
end
```

Gives me this error

`#<NameError: undefined local variable or method`current_path' for #>`

I'm using capybara version 1.1.2

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved them into a describe block and it worked.